# c: change variable type without casting

Tags: c, types, casting

I'm changing an uint32_t to a float but without changing the actual bits.

Just to be sure: I *don't wan't to cast* it. So `float f = (float) i` is the exact opposite of what I wan't to do because it changes bits.

I'm going to use this to convert my (pseudo) random numbers to float without doing unneeded math.

What I'm currently doing and what is already working is this:

```
float random_float( uint64_t seed ) {

    // Generate random and change bit format to ieee
    uint32_t asInt = (random_int( seed ) & 0x7FFFFF) | (0x7E000000>>1);

    // Make it a float
    return *(float*)(void*)&asInt; // <-- pretty ugly and nees a variable
}
```

**The Question**: Now I'd like to get rid of the `asInt` variable and I'd like to know if there is a better / not so ugly way then getting the address of this variable, casting it twice and dereferencing it again?

Comment: Interessting question, could you state why you need this microoptimization?

Comment: `float result; memcpy( &result, &asInt, sizeof(uint32_t));return result;`.  You might also want to have some sort of static assertion that `sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t)` even if that is quite common today.

Comment: To expand on @MichaelBurr's point: What you are currently doing is violating the strict aliasing rule, and is undefined behavior.

Comment: Use a union. Or wrap the casts in a macro.

Comment: @ckruczek: What kind of microoptimization are you talking about? If you mean not using float division: That's because this runs on an microcontroller which has to implement it very costly in software.

Comment: Yep I was talking about division. Ok thanks for your answer. Now it makes sense to me, to do it :)

Comment: @MichaelBurr: That would remove the need for an uint32_t variable but introduce an float variable and make it sort of even more complicated / ugly.  You're right with the static assumtion.

Comment: Note that there a re a lot of _undefined_ codes in the binary representation of a float. Further signal special conditions, like NAN, +INF, -INF, etc. There are also two 0 representations (+0, -0). Do you really have thought about **all** implications?

Comment: @Olaf: You're right of cause :) I'm currently reading this: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html but not to the end by now.

Comment: @Olaf, [IEEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) leaves no undefined space, just a lot of NaNs.  They all require an exponent of 0xff, and the OP's code sets the exponent to 0x7e to give a random value in the range of [0.5,1.0).

Comment: @sh1: You are basically right. For NaN, however, the lower matissa bits are platform-defined, so the codes could very well be seen "not defined by the standard". So, the value is still valid. In that sense, "undefined" is wrong - right.

Comment: Sheintod: We might have quite different definitions about a "hobby". Even for "hobby", I actually prefer knowing what I do:-). However, as that is my Job, I actually _do_ have to know what I do. Most important is you really know the actual format your platform uses. Then, you dig that implementaion deeply in a system-dependent library and forget about the internals (still comment the code very well !!)

Comment: @Olaf: I do software development for a living, too. But I'm more in other programming languages. This code happens to be for some kind of mood-light I'm currently building for my bedroom. The question wasn't intended to discuss ieee but more of: how can i get c to do what I want. (Namely to use that bits that I have and regard them as float.) So it's more about learning some stuff I just find interessting. But at least when I'm done I will know what I have done ;)

Comment: @Scheintod: while the `memcpy()` doesn't get rid of a local and in fact adds another one, it has the advantages of being simple and well defined - unless there's there's something I don't understand about floating point representation. That's quite likely, but is also being discussed in other commentary (and the `memcpy()` doesn't make things worse than the reinterpret-style cast). I believe that the `memcpy()` is actually more understandable than the reinterpret-style double cast. And finally, I think there's not much value in removing locals just for the sake of removing them. They're cheap.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79555/discussion-on-question-by-scheintod-c-change-variable-type-without-casting).

Comment: The best is yet to come... Why can't ppl just phrase a clear question? Anyway, I still do not understand why that would be more ugly than the thing as such? This **is__ ugly platform-dependent stuff anyway. If will not become less ugly with flowers all around. Fact is, you _cannot_ do such things "beatiful". You might use a pointer to a union, but that is still ugly and would hide the actual stuff. I'd prefer the explicit casts (Python's credo: "explicit is better than implicit"). Note to care not to aliasing: instantly return after the cast or do that in a function (possibly inline).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try union - as long as you make sure the types are identical in memory sizes:

```
union convertor {
    int asInt;
    float asFloat;
};
```

Then you can assign your int to asFloat (or the other way around if you want to). I use it a lot when I need to do bitwise operations on one hand and still get a uint32_t representation on the number on the other hand

[EDIT]
Like many of the commentators rightfully state, you must take into consideration values that are not presentable by integers like like NAN, +INF, -INF, +0, -0.

Comment: This looks like a nice idea. But it still needs an additional variable, does it?

Comment: Nope, sizeof(union convertor) == 4, a union size, as opposed to a struct only uses the maximum memory needed to keep its most expansive component.

Comment: I ended up with `float random_float( uint64_t seed ) {                                                          
    union _convertor c = { ((random_int( seed ) & 0x7FFFFF) | (0x7E000000>>1)) };              
    return c.asFloat;                                                                          
}                                                                                              
` which is a nicer and works. What I'm refering to is `c` variable here. Or do you suggest casting to the union?

Comment: This is exactly the way to do it, I'd be more explicit about the type I'm using just to make it more readable: c.asInt = ((random_int( seed ) & 0x7FFFFF) | (0x7E000000>>1)); return c.asFloat.

Comment: An `int` can have any size beyond 15+1 bits. And it does actually. Also, a float has undefined/special encoding for special/non-value conditions (NAN, +/-INF, +/-0), etc. Also, the vaues depend on endianess fo float and int, not just the size of the int. Truely: forget about that!

Comment: @olaf - hence the "as long as you make sure the types are identical in memory sizes" note. This is an architecture specific solution. About the second part you are correct, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I refered to your first comment. My comment also was not just about memory size. And I forget to mention alignment.

Answer (score 1):

So you seem to want to generate floating point numbers between 0.5 and 1.0 judging from your code.

Assuming that your microcontroller has a standard C library with floating point support, you can do this all standards compliant without actually involving any floating point operations, all you need is the `ldexp` function that itself doesn't actually do any floating point math.

This would look something like this:

```
return ldexpf((1 << 23) + random_thing_smaller_than_23_bits(), -24);
```

The trick here is that we happen to know that IEEE754 binary32 floating point numbers have integer precision between 2^23 and 2^24 (I could be off-by-one here, double check please, I'm translating this from some work I've done on doubles). So the compiler should know how to convert that number to a float trivially. Then `ldexp` multiplies that number by 2^-24 by just changing the bits in the exponent. No actual floating point operations involved and no undefined behavior, the code is fully portable to any standard C implementation with IEEE754 numbers. Double check the generated code, but a good compiler and c library should not use any floating point instructions here.

If you want to peek at some experiments I've done around generating random floating point numbers [you can peek at this github repo](https://github.com/art4711/random-double). It's all about doubles, but should be trivially translatable to floats.

Comment: Looks interesting. Actually I'm trying to generate randoms in range 0..1 but I'm not there yet.

Comment: @Scheintod: if that's what you want, why would that be so complicated using standard? If hard-FPU, the code might not be more complicated than the hack, with soft-FPU, the compiler might be able to optimize so the result generates (almost) the same code. Have you actually tried even to compile and look at your code? Such optimization should always be the last ressort and only if really necessary.

Comment: Hmm.. ldexpf (C11, 7.12.6.6) already requires a float argument. I suppose the TO wants to contruct a float from an integer.

Comment: Not sure that `ldexpf` is any more efficient than `rand24b() * 0x1p-24)`.  Its first argument is float so that conversion still has to be done, and a sensible compiler should recognise a multiply by power of two and do what's most efficient there.

Comment: Also, your `r0to1()` implementation on github appears to have the same flaws as a direct cast and scale from a uniform integer distribution to a floating-point number.  That is, as the exponent approaches -52, you get fewer and fewer variable bits in your mantissa.  This means that you can only return about 2^53 unique values, when a double can represent roughly 2^62 values between 0 and 1.0.

Comment: @sh1 That's actually on purpose. It's documented in the comments. The choice is between having uniform distance between all numbers that are possible to generate (which reduces the number of bits in the mantissa) or to make all the numbers in the range possible, but then some are more likely to be returned than others. I chose the first option.

Comment: So why all the complexity?  Why not simply `rand52b() * 0x1p-52`, or the same thing using `ldexp()`?  The bit scan will be done in hardware during the conversion anyway.  Not need to repeat it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Reinterpreting the binary representation of an int to a float would result in major problems:

- There are a lot of undefined codes in the binary representation of a float.
- Other codes represent special conditions, like NAN, +INF, -INF, +0, -0 (sic!), etc.

Also, if that is a random value, even if catching all non-value representations, that would yield a very bad random distribution.

If you are working on an MCU without FPU, you should better think about avoiding float at all. An alternative might be fraction or scaled integers. There are many implementations of algorithms which use float, but can be easily converted to fixed point types with acceptable loss of precision (or even none at all). Some might even yield more precision than float (note that single precision float has only 23 bits of mantissa, an int32 would have 31 bits (+ 1 sign for either), same for a fractional or fixed scaled int.

Note that C11 added (optional) support for _Frac. You might want to research on that.

**Edit:**

According you your comments, you seem to convert the int to a float in range 0..<1. For that, you can assemble the float using bit operations on an uint32_t (e.g. the original value). You just need to follow the IEEE format (presumed your toolchain does comply to the C standard! See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

The result (still uint32_t) can then be reinterpreted by a union or pointer as described by others already. Pack that in a system-dependent, well-commented library and dig it deep. Do not forget to check about endianess and alignment (likely both the same for float and uint32_t, but important for the bit-ops).

Comment: There are hacks that require integer operations on float's raw data, like the famous "fast inverse sqrt".

Comment: @D-side:As much as any soft-FPU has to (that isqrt _is_ actually one aspect of a Soft-PFU. However, that is deep down implementation stuff. The question above does not imply such. And as the TO apparently is not aware about reserved codes, I do not assume that's what he actually wants. However, I mostly show the drawbacks; he is still free to ignore me.